# Cancel rgrep during execution

Tags: rgrep

I'm recursively grepping a large project using `M-x rgrep`.

After a few seconds pass I see the text I was searching for. At this point how can I cancel the search whilst preserving the buffer contents?

Comment: **Emacs, internal process killing, any command?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627289/emacs-internal-process-killing-any-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`C-c C-k`** should be bound to `kill-compilation`, which should do the job.